# Spatial Join if more than 50% of join feature overlay target feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-joins, spatial-join, overlay

My ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10.3 includes 2 Shapefiles:

1. Buildings footprint (polygons).
2. Red shapes (polygons) which includes information for each building.

The task is creating new layer that contains Red shapes (target features) with corresponding footprints (join features), if more than 50% of "Red Shape" overlay building footprint.

I tried "Spatial Join" with match options INTERSECT, HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN and WITHIN_A_DISTANCE with negative value in search radius, but i can't achieve the desired result. For example in attached picture; Red shape No. 4 shall be included while the shapes 1, 2 and 3 shall be excluded since they contribution very small on building footprint.

[image]

How I would do that in ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider calculating the area of each red polygon (create a new field for this calculated geometry), intersecting it with the building footprints and comparing that new area with the initial red area.

If it is 50% (IntersectArea >= 0.5 * InitialArea) or more of the initial red area, keep it, otherwise you can query it out or flag it using an additional field if you prefer. The remaining polygons can then be spatially joined with the building footprints for your final output.

Check out the [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm) tool for calculating geometries within ModelBuilder.

Comment: True; I've edited my answer to link to the ArcMap equivalent. If that doesn't end up working, I'd also consider just using the field calculator along with the expressions outlined in this help document:

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_the_Calculate_Field_tool/005s00000029000000/